# Trying to install wptools in my Anaconda enviroment to use in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to install wptools in my python 3 Anaconda environment to use in Jupyter. Since it is a non-conda package, I used pip. But I get this error:

> (py3) C:\Users\owner>pip install wptools
>
> Collecting wptools
>
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/5c/0d8af5532e44477edeb3dac81d3a611ea75827a18b6b4068c3cc2188bfe5/wptools-0.4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages (from wptools) (2018.10.15)
>
> Collecting lxml (from wptools)
>
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/c7/e088bf0f4f81e6b366cc2de12939c559b588b9525ad76215d122e69151ed/lxml-4.2.5-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (3.2MB)
>
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.2MB 1.2MB/s
>
> Collecting html2text (from wptools)
>
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/20/de2b458ef434713053dd83209a03a5431ebe0527c8e14d9ae7838ff67d8a/html2text-2018.1.9-py3-none-any.whl
>
> Collecting pycurl (from wptools)
>
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
>
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>
> Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-39cbrz2h\pycurl\

Comment: And then what happened after you followed the advice?

Comment: I'm new to this. I tried "pip install wptools --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl" but all it said was "no such option: --curl-dir". I'm sure I'm not supposed to just copy and paste it, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

- I just had the same problem and solved it using `pip install wptools`.
- I am not an expert and it seems weird that I cannot install it using the GUI (Anaconda Navigator).

**Update:** I see that I misread your question and that my solution did not work for you :).

---

```
(base) C:\Users\Biest>conda install wptools
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - wptools

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

[image: strong text]
*(Error Message)*

[image]
*(Solution)*

[image]
*(GUI does not work)*

[image]

(The "black" window is the `Anaconda Prompt`.)

Answer (score 0):

here's what you'll do

1. in your command prompt since you're already in a Conda environment use Conda to install pip (conda install pip)
2. afterwards pip install wptools and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and pycurl was the main cause in my case.
To fix it, I started by installing pycurl before installing wptools

```
conda install pycurl
pip install wptools
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably related to `setuptools`. Upgrade `setuptools` and reinstall wptools.

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
pip install wptools --ignore-installed
```